# How to linking Javascript and GWT to passing parameter

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I've this GWT code:

```
Button button = new Button("Search");
                button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        loadData();

                    }
                });

...

    private native void loadData()  /*-{
        $wnd.loadGrid();
    }-*/;
```

and this Javascript code:

```
...
loadGrid : function (){ 
            alert("Testing JSNI");
        },
...
```

It doesn't works and the error is:

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError) : undefined is not a function
```

This is an example code because my target is to pass parameters from js to GWT, but I don't understand why it doesn't run. What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How to you load the javascript code ?

Comment: In my html page so: '<script type="text/javascript"  lang="javascript" src="./ProjectName/ProjectName.nocache.js">'. Other pieces of js code are loaded.

Comment: Not the .nocache.js (GWT code) but the javascript where your are the loadGrid method ?

Comment: In nameProject.gwt.xml. I think the problem is in code syntax above because it works for other JSNI code, do you agree?

Comment: With browser console, can you call the loadGrid function ?

Comment: From Chrome Console: 'loadGrid
ReferenceError: loadGrid is not defined
message: "loadGrid is not defined"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
<function scope>
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error'

Comment: Can you share your javascript file ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `loadGrid` function in the window context:

```
window.loadGrid = function(){...}
```

Otherwise call your function from its appropriate object container, for instance:

```
window.myObject = {
   loadGrid: function(){...}
}

private native void loadData() /*-{
   $wnd.myObject.loadGrid()
}-*/;
```

Comment: It seems doesn't accept this syntax: '     [java] SEVERE: input.js:74015: ERROR - Parse error. missing : after property id
     [java]             window.loadGrid = function()
     [java]                     ^                     '